# Add text to first video, add audio and watermark to second video and then add crossfading to these two videos and one another video using one command?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have four commands that is working perfectly but i want only one command to do this task.

**Commands:**

```
ffmpeg -i ' . config('medialibrary.s3.domain') . '/listing_video/intro.mp4' . ' -vf "drawtext=fontfile=' . storage_path('assets/video/FutuMd.ttf') . ': text=' . $this->listing->car->name . ': x=300: y=450: fontsize=40: fontcolor=white: enable='between(t,2,5)'" introfinal.mp4

ffmpeg -i mainvideo.mp4 -i '.config('medialibrary.s3.domain').'/listing_video/EnergyAudio.mp3'.' -filter_complex "[1:a]volume=enable='between(t,0,32)':volume=-10dB[1a];[0:a][1a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a aac -ac 2 -shortest mainvideooutput.mp4

ffmpeg -i mainvideooutput.mp4 -i ' . storage_path('assets/image/vcs-watermark-video.png') . ' -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5" -codec:a copy mainvideofinal.mp4

ffmpeg -y -i introfinal.mp4 -i mainvideofinal.mp4  -i ' . config('medialibrary.s3.domain') . '/listing_video/outro.mp4' . ' -f lavfi -i color=black:s=1280x720:d=30 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
[1:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=31:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+6/TB[v1]; \
[2:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+38/TB[v2]; \
[3][v0]overlay[over1]; \
[over1][v1]overlay[over2]; \
[over2][v2]overlay=format=yuv420[outv]; \
[0][1][2]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[outa]" \
-vcodec libx264 -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" '.$fileName.'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are all videos the same resolution?

Comment: yes, all videos are in same resolution.

Comment: @Gyan in your answer after answer command runs new video created but audio of second video is cut after some time like last 8 seconds of second video audio is mute why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -i intro.mp4 -i mainvideo.mp4 -i outro.mp4 -i EnergyAudio.mp3 \
       -i vcs-watermark-video.png \
       -filter_complex \
"[0:v]drawtext=...,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
 [1:v][4]overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=31:d=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
 [2:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; \
 [3:a]volume=enable='between(t,0,32)':volume=-10dB[3a];[1:a][3a]amerge=inputs=2,pan=stereo[maina]; \
 [v0][0][v1][maina][v2][2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" \
       -vcodec libx264 -c:a aac -ac 2 -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" '.$fileName.'
```

Comment: Thanks! your command is merged 3 videos but sound of second video is cut and also audio is not added in second video.

Comment: Replace `amerge=inputs=2` with `amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest` and remove pan filter.